# How to add write permissions to default S3 trigger lambda role?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Seeing this warning from AWS, I'm updating from a S3 trigger lambda function template.

"This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition."

I added the second statement, with four actions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        },
        
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket"
        }              
        
    ]
}
```

When I click on "show remaining", I see
"S3
Limited: Read
BucketName | string like | All
None"

Every resource has None.

Why am I not seeing "write" listed here and is this an issue?

Comment: The arn `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket` matches the bucket.  It does *not* match objects in the bucket.  For that you'd want `arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*`.  All 4 of the actions you specified only apply to objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource ARNs that you've given only apply to Buckets, not to objects within those Buckets.  The API actions listed only apply to objects.  So your policy doesn't give permission to do anything.

Try the following policy instead:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I don't recall off hand if multiple wildcards are permitted in a Resource constraint; you may need to replace `"arn:aws:s3:::*/*"` with `"*"`.

For details on the types of resources required for S3 API actions, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html.